# How to copy data in bulk from Kinesis -> Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

When i read about AWS data pipeline the idea immediately struck - produce statistics to kinesis and create a job in pipeline that will consume data from kinesis and COPY it to redshift every hour. All in one go.

But it seems there is no node in pipeline that can consume kinesis. So now i have two possible plans of action:

1. Create instance where Kinesis's data will be consumed and sent to S3 split by hours. Pipeline will copy from there to Redshift.
2. Consume from Kinesis and produce COPY directly to Redshift on the spot.

What should I do? Is there no way to connect Kinesis to redshift using AWS services only, without custom code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now possible to do so without user-code via a new managed service called [Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html). It manages the desired buffering intervals, temp uploads to s3, upload to Redshift, error handling and auto throughput management.

Comment: This seems exactly what i was looking for at the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is already done for you!
If you use the Kinesis Connector Library, there is a built-in connector to Redshift

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors

Depending on the logic you have to process connector can be really easy to implement.

Comment: I was looking to create some kind of mechanism with no-user-code, but it seems it not possible at the moment. And i starting to think it's not feasible because of nature kinesis - it's just a queue, apache kafka on steroids. I'll accepting the answer because it's the only possible one. Thank you!

Comment: Does this custom connector, which performs bulk copies from Kinesis -> Redshift every hour, get uploaded to AWS?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but yes if you use the connector from Kinesis to Redshift, then yes all the data is stored AWS Redshift data warehouse. The "every hour" part is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and orchestrate complete pipeline with InstantStack to read data from Kinesis, transform it and push it into any Redshift or S3.